# Определение текста в элементе через jquery

Tags: jquery

Всем привет! Вопрос, собственно, в следующем:

Есть элемент с классом ".catalog__items__item", у него есть несколько дочерних элементов, один из них - h3

Я почему-то не могу найти именно h3 через jquery.

Вот код:

```
$(document).on('click', '.catalog__items__item', function(){
    $title = $(this).children('h3').text();
    alert($title);
});
```

При выборе всех дочерних элементов все проходит нормально, т.е.

```
$(document).on('click', '.catalog__items__item', function(){
    $title = $(this).children().text();
    alert($title);
});
```

Работает корректно, выводятся все элементы.

Скажите, пожалуйста, что я делаю не так с определением значения h3?

UPD:

Совсем забыл добавить html:

```
<div class="catalog__items__item" id="product">
    <h3>Сердечко с розами2</h3>
    <img src="../img/1.jpg" alt="продукт" width="200"
        height="150">
    <p class="size">Размер: на выбор</p>
    <p class="flowers">Количество цветов: 15-35</p>             
    <p class="price">Цена: от 1000 р</p>
    <div class="buttons">                   
        <a href="#popup_buy" class="buy popup">Купить</a>
    </div>
```

Comment: можно показать код html

Comment: Что-то тогда не совсем понимаю: 
Как сделать, чтобы он ссылался на div?

В  идеале схема такая:
1. Человек нажимает на товар
2. Значение товара передается в переменную, которая передается в модальное окно
3. Открывается модальное окно

Comment: У вас все работает

Comment: Если бы все работало, думаю, я бы сюда не писал :)

Comment: я провeрил ваш код, работает, получаю текст в алерте

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/azzyjaam/
сотрите сами
ваш код 1 в 1. Смотрите ваше подкл. скриптов, или может еще что перебивает

Comment: Да, спасибо, ребят. Сижу и унываю, не понимаю, в чем даже дело может быть.

Comment: Самое странное - убрал все скрипты кроме jquery, но все равно ничего не выводит

Comment: ошибки в консоли есть?

Comment: у вас помимо английского других языков в системе не установлено? скопируйте `h3` из `html` в селектор `jquery`